# Do mature minors have the right to privately consult with a medical professional?

Tags: united-states, privacy, medical, minor, human-rights

The title should be relatively self-explanatory. Do mature minors (aged 16 or older) have a legal right to privately consult with a medical professional, free from the involvement of a parent, guardian, or some other individual *in loco parentis*?

If there exists any applicable state law, Minnesota is my area of concern.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from User6726 is true, but it leaves out some things. The minor may consent to medical treatment if he/she is living apart from the parents and managing his/her own finances. (Minn. Stat. § 144.341)

The full list of things a minor can consent to aside from that, are as follows:

> - to determine the presence of or to treat pregnancy and conditions associated
>   with pregnancy
> - for sexually transmitted infections
> - for alcohol or other drug abuse (Minn. Stat. § 144.343, subd. 1)
> - hepatitis B vaccinations (Minn. Stat. § 144.3441) and
> - blood donation (only those 17 and over; a 16-year-old can donate with
>   written consent from a parent or guardian) (Minn. Stat. § 145.41).
> - Health services may be provided to minors without the consent of a parent if, in the
>   health professional’s judgment, treatment should be given without delay, and if
>   obtaining consent would result in delay or denial of treatment

That list and a few other items can be found here: https://www.house.leg.state.mn.us/hrd/pubs/ss/ssminorhc.pdf

Comment: Does the minor's ability to consent to these procedures necessarily imply that they have to be kept confidential from the parents after the fact?

Comment: HIPPA rules would say that the records are private in the minor is allowed to consent, but MN has a law saying that if not notifying the parent would cause serious harm the parent should be notified.  https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/144.346

Comment: Why specifically hepatitis B, and not other vaccinations?

Answer (score 1):

If the minor is legally able to consent to the treatment, the parents do not have any rights to the minor's treatment. The [Consent of Minors for Health Services](https://www.revisor.mn.gov/statutes/cite/144.341) says when that is the case – living apart, married, have given birth, also for diagnosing pregnancy, substance abuse, "veneral disease", Hep-B vaccination (there is an abortion-related counter-command). If, for example, a minor wanted to be examined for a sprained ankle, that is not covered by the various minor-consent laws, so a parent/guardian would have to give consent, and would be entitled to be present during the consultation.

Comment: This covers some but not all cases.